# Get Constructor (Or Methods) Parameter Annotation Using Reflection

Tags: java, reflection, constructor, annotations

How do I obtain the annotation from a parameter within the constructor arguments. I have tried...

```
Class<?>[] params = constructor.getParameterTypes();
    if(params.length > 0) {
        paramValues = new Object[params.length];
        for(int i=0; i<params.length; i++) {                        
        Annotation[] constructorAnnotations = params[i].getAnnotations(); //This does not work.
        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`constructor.getParameterAnnotations()` returns the annotations for each parameter. For example, the annotations for the 2nd parameter are:

```
Annotation[] annotations = constructor.getParameterAnnotations()[1]
```

Comment: I tried that but sadly could not figure out how to properly read the data. Can I tell if each parameter either has an annotation or not in the correct order? Could I possibly get a little more sample code?